# Which is correct, kohm or kOhm?

Tags: resistance, units

Should the unit "Ohm" be capitalized or not?  For example, "kOhm" versus "kohm" vs "kΩ", which is most correct?

Comment: I would say it is matter of preference. IMO: kΩ > kOhm > kohm

Comment: SI standard says use lower case for units named after somebody when written out long form and capitalise the first letter for the symbol. V for volt, A for ampere, Hz for hertz, Ω for ohm, etc.

Comment: @transistor right, but kohm looks like a hybrid: long "ohm", but contracted "kilo".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my experience "kΩ" is preferred, but if you don't have the "Ω" symbol available on your computer then you need to write out the full words in lowercase: "kilo ohm".

See here for the standards on writing out SI units: [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Writing_unit_symbols_and_the_values_of_quantities)

The Wikipedia article on the [ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm) says it should be "kilohm" [(not "kiloohm")](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf)
if written out, which I've not seen in my experience, but I'll include this for full reference.

Comment: Just going to add this here to justify the need to write out the word if the symbol is lacking http://www.poynton.com/notes/units/

"Write a numeric value with units in either the journalistic style, using prefix and unit names (four kilohertz); or the scientific style, using prefix and unit symbols (4 kHz). Don't mix these styles: Do not mix a prefix name with a unit symbol (WRONG: kiloHz), or a prefix symbol with a unit name (WRONG: kHertz). Avoid "abbreviations" for units (WRONG: sec., amp); use the unit names or symbols instead. "

Comment: @Chu, That's the Symbol. ampere = A, volts = V, ohms = Ω (this is a capital Omega), coulomb = C, hertz = Hz, etc. NOT THE NAME, which is always written lowercase. All of these have capitals for their SYMBOLS unlike say meter = m, second = s, gram = g, etc.

Comment: @Dave, yes that's correct, I'll delete my original comment.

Comment: "kilo ohm" is wrong. SI prefixes are not spaced from the units. e.g. "millimeter", not "milli meter".

Comment: Tip: You can type Ω by holding Alt key and type '234' (release Alt now).  Alt + 230 = µ for µF.  I'm on Windows, dunno about Macs.

Answer (score -4):

As per the standard convention whenever the SI unit is written it is in lowercase. However symbols of units after a scientist name has to be in lower case when written full and when abbreviation is being written then it is in uppercase. In this case.( **A or ohms/Kohms**) "There should not be a period after Uppercase letter."

Comment: I don't think `Kohms` is the correct notation. Can you back your claim with a reference?

Comment: '**K**ohms' = **kelvin**-ohms. Capitals matter. 'kOhm' and 'kohm' are wrong. 'kilohm' is correct according to the standards. I think you'll find the information [here](https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/writing-si-metric-system-units#:~:text=NOT%20250%20mms.-,Capitalization,written%20as%2037%20degrees%20Celsius.) when the site is back online.

Comment: @Transistor I think you missed an 'o'. kilohm seems like an accidental portmanteau

Comment: @raaymaan, no, it's correct. See Section 9.3 of https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf. "*... there are three cases in which the final vowel of an SI prefix is
commonly omitted: megohm (not megaohm), kilohm (not kiloohm), and hectare (not hectoare). In all other
cases in which the unit name begins with a vowel, both the final vowel of the prefix and the vowel of the
unit name are retained and both are pronounced.*"

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the info!